# I want to know for what reason we cannot use “what when"

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

*What if* defined as a phrase means:

> What would result if ….? [(Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/what_if_%25E2%2580%2594%3F)
>
> *‘What if nobody shows up?’*

The differences between *if* and *when* is not the question, but if we say *what when* meaning:

> What result when….?

can we say:

*What when nobody shows up?*

and if not, why?

Comment: It is actually idiomatic, I can confirm. 'You can't ride your bike to school !' 'But Mum, what when I get up late and need to rush ?'

Comment: @NigelJ is that the same general linguistic group that uses "might could"? They seem like they could be related somehow.

Comment: @1006a I shall ask around my neighbourhood and find out what linguistic group they call themselves. 'Might could' I have never heard of.

Comment: "might could' is probably American these days. Hollywood sometimes uses it as "rustic"  expression.

Comment: Sounds totally off to me (AmE). But, linguistic note, in standard German, the word for 'if' is 'wenn', cognate with Eng 'when'. That is, it's not unnatural to have 'when' replace 'if'.

Comment: @NigelJ, ah, that's a different area altogether than I had in mind--I'm familiar with "might could" from Texan friends. I should have noticed the "Mum" in your example.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between *when* and *if* seems important in this construction.
Where *if* means that something *may* occur, *when* implies it probably *will* occur at some moment in the future.

That means that *what when nobody shows up...* sounds a bit strange, because it seems to imply that we already know that nobody will show up - which is not really a well defined event, because it presumably is equal to the current state of affairs.

On the other hand, when you organise a garden party and the dark clouds forming in the sky make it quite clear it will start raining at some point, you could ask yourself *what when it starts raining?*.

Comment: "What when nobody shows up?" sounds fine to me.

Comment: @Araucaria It sounds alright to me too, in a certain register. I'm not sure though that the elision would pass muster with educational examiners in the UK.  What you are actually saying is: "What (about the times) when nobody shows up".